# Verifying perturbation theory proof mentioned in an online article

Tags: perturbation-theory

I am reading an article mentioned here http://www.bcamath.org/documentos_public/archivos/personal/comites/course.pdf. I am stuck at page 14 where it says "Thus from (2.1.7) it follows that the coefficient of $\epsilon^{\alpha0}$ should
be zero, namely $x_0 = 0$". I couldn't prove how coeffecient $x^0$ becomes zero.

Comment: There is an issue even worse than that $x_0=0$. The leading order equation is $-1=0$! The next equation is, at $O(\epsilon^{\alpha_0})$, $x_0=0$ (all the other terms have higher powers of $\epsilon$). But $-1=0$ at leading order shows this is not the correct dominant balance.

Comment: Thanks for the verification David. The article needs to be corrected by its author.